# Mac Terminal shows the name of a network machine on the prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, command-prompt, prompt

Once I launch the terminal app, I see a network machine name before my name, any idea how to fix it.

attached screenshot.

the name before : (colon) is a network machine name[image]

Edit:

i went to system preferences and turned off file sharing, but it's still there (will check again after rebooting computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with FileSharing and everything to do with the hostname that the DNS server (usually a dynamic address-ing DHCP thing) assigns you.

So what you really want to do is modify your Bash prompt.

And [here is a tutorial that talks about how to do it](http://twistedcode.org/2007/11/customizing-your-bash-prompt/).

Comment: by the I was more concerned on how come the name came into my bash prompt, it picked it on it's own, that was the weird part

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom prompt by editing your ~/.bashrc file. Just add:

```
export PS1="\W \$"
```

If you have no .bashrc file in your user home directory just create one. :D

Comment: I want to revert to default one instead of creating a custom prompt, I've no idea how the other machine lvallone-hp appeared on my prompt, it's my colleague's machine